# Using .htaccess url rewrite in node http-server

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to run the angular application in production mode on node http-server. I removed # from URL using Angular's html5 mode and added URL rewriting rules in `.htaccess` file to keep it running in production mode.

It works fine with apache server but it's really a big pain to configure it on Linux VPS so to avoid that extra pain I was trying to use node http-server for this purpose but that `.htaccess` file config isn't working here.

How can I write the similar configuration for node server?

this is my `.htaccess` config

```
#Enable deep-linking for Angular2 routes - Redirect all calls to index.html
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess file is an Apache configuration file. But you can redirect to index.html like that :

```
http.get('*', function(req, res) {  
    res.redirect('http://example.com/index.html');
});
```

Comment: I am talking about http-server that I install globally and just run it in folder.

Comment: Oops sorry, I don't think it's possible with http-server but you can try : https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server/#single-page-application